# MySQL - How to count number of previous occurrences to current row

Tags: mysql

With the following table:

```
+----------+------+
| Platform | day  |
+----------+------+
| 1670254  |    0 |
| 1670254  |    0 |
| 1665087  |    0 |
| 1670254  |    0 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1665160  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    1 |
| 1670254  |    2 |
| 1670254  |    2 |
| 1670254  |    3 |
| 1670254  |    4 |
| 1667145  |    5 |
```

I want to add a third column that counts the number of occurrences of previous dates. For example, on day 1, platform 1670254 performed 3 previous operations.

The result should show something like:

```
+----------+------+-----------+
| Platform | day  |  Previous | 
+----------+------+-----------+
| 1670254  |    0 |     0     |
| 1670254  |    0 |     0     |
| 1665087  |    0 |     0     |
| 1670254  |    0 |     0     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1665160  |    1 |     0     |
| 1670254  |    1 |     3     |
| 1670254  |    2 |     9     |
| 1670254  |    2 |     9     |
| 1670254  |    3 |    11     |
| 1670254  |    4 |    12     |
| 1667145  |    5 |     0     |
```

Comment: You have no primary key. Without one, this is insoluble.

Comment: @Strawberry he wants count all previous, no need a PK just count previous days.

Comment: Might be good to post the code you are using to generate the current implementation.

Comment: @pcalkins Original data comes in (Platform, Date of Operation). Date is Y-M-d. I ended with this table with a datediff(Date,lag(Date) over ()) implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need a correlated query to get the previous day for each platform.

**[SQL DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/om4qCYUtgJYL5nkSMvaX6Q/0)**

```
   SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(Platform) 
              FROM YourTable t2 
              WHERE t1.Platform = t2.Platform
                AND t1.day > t2.day) as Previous
   FROM YourTable t1
```